# PL/SQL how to skip execution of script if similar value if found in the Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to create an Oracle PL/SQL insert script. This is just one time insert statement, and if the script gets executed multiple times and if similar values are available in `Table` it should skip the execution.

Now if the script gets executed again, I want it to complete successfully. However, I do not want to enter duplicate data if the similar record is available in the table.

Here is my script:

```
Set SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN

INSERT INTO TableA
        (First,
     Last,
     Address,
     City,
     State,
     Zip
         )

VALUES
       ('Alex',
    'Roark',
    '25 El Camino Real',
    'San Roman',
    'CA',
    '94008'
       );

INSERT INTO TableA
        (First,
     Last,
     Address,
     City,
     State,
     Zip
         )

VALUES
       ('William',
    'Chan',
    '3700 Baltimore Ave',
    'Detroit',
    'MI',
    '21003'
       );

INSERT INTO TableA
        (First,
     Last,
     Address,
     City,
     State,
     Zip
         )

VALUES
       ('Petty',
    'Garg',
    '1980 Fernando Ct',
    'Austin',
    'TX',
    '85002'
       );

INSERT INTO TableA
        (First,
     Last,
     Address,
     City,
     State,
     Zip
         )

VALUES
       ('Thomas',
    'Gregory',
    '56 E Washington Blvd',
    'Philadelphia',
    'PA',
    '19803'
       );

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Insert Completed Successfully');

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION

 WHEN dup_val_on_index

  THEN  ROLLBACK;

END;
/

Set serveroutput off;
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: have you tried it with your script?

Comment: How about changing your exception handler for `dup_val_on_index` from `rollback;` to `null;`?

Comment: how about implementing a unique primary key in your table or maybe a column that will make a record distinguishable from the others like an id? that way you can implement a unique index to it then that's the time you can actually use a dup_val_on_index exception

Answer (score 1):

your question is not understandable as the code you are providing will not work in such case.
In your code, as soon as you get exception your whole process will go to end and rest of the insert statements will be left without process.

You Should follow some steps here -
1) Create PK or Unique key on the table so that you can differentiate between rows on some basis.
2) While inserting any value, do check on that column value if the value you are going to insert already exists in the table or not and then proceed.

Try to change using steps above. Please Share if you feel any problem then.

Comment: Thanks Udit. I do understand that I need to create PK on one of the field. Just want to clear that I just want to create one time script to load the table. And if by mistake some one can re-run that script, It will still finish successfully but will not insert any new record or does not affect the previously inserted record.